# How to have multiple charts in a single page canvasjs php

Tags: javascript, php, canvasjs

I am using canvasJS to display two charts in one page.

When i have two charts in a page only the second chart appears, the first never shows up.

This is my code

main page

```html
<?php include("top_airlines.php"); ?>
<?php include("genderrange.php"); ?>
```

This is the code for the first chart genderrange.php

```html
<?php 

$dataPoints1 = array( 
 array("label"=>"Male", "y"=>5),
 array("label"=>"Female", "y"=>1),
);



        
        
        
       ?> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
 
 
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 title: {
  text: "Gender Ratio of Applicants"
 },
 subtitles: [{
//  text: "November 2017"
 }],
 data: [{
  type: "pie",
  yValueFormatString: "#,##0.00\"\"",
  indexLabel: "{label} ({y})",
  dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
 }]
});
chart.render();
 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer1" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code of the second chart. The variables are different but they still override the first one. top_airlines.php

```html
<?php 

$malecount=5;
$femalecount=1;
$dataPoints2 = array( 
 array("label"=>"Male", "y"=>$malecount),
 array("label"=>"Female", "y"=>$femalecount),
);


?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
 
 
var chart2 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 title: {
  text: "Gender Ratio of Applicants"
 },
 subtitles: [{
//  text: "November 2017"
 }],
 data: [{
  type: "pie",
  yValueFormatString: "#,##0.00\"\"",
  indexLabel: "{label} ({y})",
  dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
 }]
});
chart2.render();
 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>   

<br>
```

Comment: These are two complete seperate pages and not a single one - can you share the exact code that triggers your problem?

Comment: yes they are two complete pages, but as you can see from the mainpage code i am including them both into a single page (as recommended by canvasjs website). When i combine them into a single page only the second chart shows up @NicoHaase

Comment: Have you tried validating the markup for that "combined" page? Having two `<html>`, `<head>`,  and `<body>` elements does not look good to me

Comment: Additionally, have you checked your browser's error console?

Comment: i removed the html elements still no solution, as for browsers error console i dont know how to do that @NicoHaase

Comment: @ahmed right click -> inspect and then select the console tab.

Comment: @PeterMeadley the console tab is empty no errors are present.

Comment: And what have you tried to further debug the problem? Like checking whether both `onload` functions are triggered after all (which, if not happening, would make that problem completely unrelated to both CanvasJS or PHP)? Checking whether if only the second one is present, that chart is shown?

Comment: Expanding on what @NicoHaase said, consider putting a console.log in both onload functions ex. console.log("onload 1") and checking the console again. If you don't see both console logs then one of them isn't being triggered.

Comment: I am getting  `Array to string conversion` at  `echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)`